# SQL Oracle: how to get count of columns per view per schema from a metadata table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Metadata table that contains the following info:

[image: meta table]

I would like to build a Query that shows the count (*) of each View per schema, something like

[image: result]

I am not quite sure how to start? in the matedata table only the name of the view per schema is stored.

do anyone has a suggestion please, thx

Comment: Do you arbitrarily want to show the counts of _all_ views in all schemas?  Or, are there are a handful of fixed and known views on which you want to report?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to query each view independently to get the real time count. You can generate SQL statements dynamically using below query:

```
select 'select count(*) as '||view_name||' from '||owner||'.'||view_name||';'
from all_views
where (owner ,view_name) in (select schema_name, view_name from metadata) ;
```

**OR**

You can do it dynamically using below PL/SQL block. Better to have results inserted in a table:

```
declare
    v_cnt integer;
begin

    for r in (select owner, view_name from all_views
              where (owner ,view_name) in (select schema_name, view_name 
                                           from metadata)) 
    loop
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || r.owner||'.'||view_name 
            into v_cnt;
        insert into cnt_table(view_name,owner,total_count)
        values (r.view_name,r.owner,v_cnt);
    end loop;

end;
```

Comment: @django_unchained: many thx for the hint! is there any way to execute the generated individual queries at once i.e. like a procedure?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: It's safer to check for `(owner, view_name)` in one step, to avoid accidents where `schema_name` exists and `view_name` exists but there's no view `schema_name.view_name`.

Comment: good point. Thanks!